# I need to create substrings out of a main string with varying window length

Tags: perl, substring

I have the following sequence

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

In this I have a substring JKLM.
I want to create sub strings of varying lengths. For example I want 6 to 12 sequence length on either side of JKLM

The answer is supposed to be like this

```
6 length
HIJKLM,
IJKLMN,
JKLMNO

7 length
GHIJKLM,
HIJKLMN,
IJKLMNO,
JKLMNOP
```

`8 length`..... and so on

I am very new to programming and it would be good if someone can provide me the source code in perl.

Comment: How do you want to specify the initial substring? By offset and length, or by content? And what about *4 length* and *5 length*, and do you want to go all the way up to *26 length*?

Answer (score 1):

Use positive lookahead assertions to enable overlap between matches.

The following displays the results for strings of length 6 to 9, but this could easily be expanded:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = join '', 'A'..'Z';
my $search = 'JKLM';

for my $len (6..9) {
    my $dist = $len - length $search;
    while ($string =~ m/(?=.{0,$dist}\Q$search\E)(?=(.{$len}))/g) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
HIJKLM
IJKLMN
JKLMNO
GHIJKLM
HIJKLMN
IJKLMNO
JKLMNOP
FGHIJKLM
GHIJKLMN
HIJKLMNO
IJKLMNOP
JKLMNOPQ
EFGHIJKLM
FGHIJKLMN
GHIJKLMNO
HIJKLMNOP
IJKLMNOPQ
JKLMNOPQR
```

For less complex tools, it's also possible to just use [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) and [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) to build this list of values.  In fact, if you are that new to programming, those are the tools that I'd advise that you learn first.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should suit you

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

for my $size (6, 7, 8, 13) {
  printf "%d length\n", $size;
  print "$_\n" for windows($s, 'JKLM', $size);
  print "\n";
}

sub windows {

  my ($str, $substr, $size) = @_;

  return unless $str =~ /\Q$substr\E/;

  my ($strlen, $substrlen) = map length, $str, $substr;
  return if $substrlen > $size;

  my $start = $-[0];
  my $end = $start + $substrlen;

  # Calculate the earliest offset so that the string contains
  # the whole window and the window contains the whole substring
  #
  my $wfirst = $end - $size;
  $wfirst = 0 if $wfirst < 0;

  # Calculate the latest offset so that the string contains
  # the whole window and the window contains the whole substring
  #
  my $wlast = $start + $size;
  $wlast = $strlen if $wlast > $strlen;
  $wlast -= $size;

  map { substr $str, $_, $size } $wfirst .. $wlast;
}
```

**output**

```
6 length
HIJKLM
IJKLMN
JKLMNO

7 length
GHIJKLM
HIJKLMN
IJKLMNO
JKLMNOP

8 length
FGHIJKLM
GHIJKLMN
HIJKLMNO
IJKLMNOP
JKLMNOPQ

13 length
ABCDEFGHIJKLM
BCDEFGHIJKLMN
CDEFGHIJKLMNO
DEFGHIJKLMNOP
EFGHIJKLMNOPQ
FGHIJKLMNOPQR
GHIJKLMNOPQRS
HIJKLMNOPQRST
IJKLMNOPQRSTU
JKLMNOPQRSTUV
```

Comment: Takes 50% of the time taken by Miller's solution for the usage pattern in Miller's answer. [Benchmark](http://pastebin.com/7LuaMwXe)